# How to fix "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'"

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to make a form to edit data of a specific item in a DB. When I submit I get this error:

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `items` set `0` = Title, `1` = ? where `ID` = 2)
```

This is how the form redirects:

```
<form action="{{ url('updateItem/'.$item->ID)}}" method="post" id="updateForm">
```

Function in controller:

```
public function updateItem($id, Request $request)
{
    $Title = $request->input('Title');
    $Kool = $request->input('Koolhydraten');
    $Vet = $request->input('Vet');
    $Eiwitten = $request->input('Eiwitten');
    $Suikers = $request->input('Suikers');

    Item::where('ID', $id)
        ->update(['Title', $Title])
        ->update(['Koolhydraten', $Kool])
        ->update(['Vet', $Vet])
        ->update(['Eiwitten', $Eiwitten])
        ->update(['Suikers', $Suikers]);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

modify your update query

```
Item::where('ID', $id)
        ->update(['Title'=> $Title,'Koolhydraten'=>$Kool,'Vet'=> $Vet,'Eiwitten' => $Eiwitten,'Suikers'=> $Suikers]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use array with key-value pair as `update()` parameter. The key needs to be same as column name you want to update and the value is the value to be updated.

When you did `->update(['Title', $Title])` this `['Title', $Title]` counts as 2 elements of array which is equivalent to:

```php
[0 => 'Title', 1 => $Title]
```

the key will be 0 and 1 respectively. Hence why the error shows it can't find column 0.

The correct query should be:

```php
Item::where('ID', $id)->update([
    'Title'        => $Title,
    'Koolhydraten' => $Kool,
    'Vet'          => $Vet,
    'Eiwitten'     => $Eiwitten,
    'Suikers'      => $Suikers
]);
```